# for loop to extract header for a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, for-loop

I am a newbie in python. I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    A   B   C   D   E
0   1   0   1   0   1
1   0   1   0   0   1
2   0   1   1   1   0
3   1   0   0   1   0
4   1   0   0   1   1
```

How can I write a for loop to gather the column names for each row. I expect my result set looks like that:

```
    A   B   C   D   E   Result
0   1   0   1   0   1   ACE
1   0   1   0   0   1   BE
2   0   1   1   1   0   BCD
3   1   0   0   1   0   AD
4   1   0   0   1   1   ADE
```

Anyone can help me with that? Thank you!

Answer (score 9):

The `dot` function is done for that purpose as you want the matrix dot product between your matrix and the vector of column names:

```
df.dot(df.columns)
Out[5]: 
0    ACE
1     BE
2    BCD
3     AD
4    ADE
```

If your dataframe is numeric, then obtain the boolean matrix first by test your `df` against 0:

```
(df!=0).dot(df.columns)
```

PS: Just assign the result to the new column

```
df['Result'] = df.dot(df.columns)

df
Out[7]: 
   A  B  C  D  E Result
0  1  0  1  0  1    ACE
1  0  1  0  0  1     BE
2  0  1  1  1  0    BCD
3  1  0  0  1  0     AD
4  1  0  0  1  1    ADE
```

Comment: @zihan. what going on hidden from view is Boolean indexing eval. This ONLY works because your matrix values are 0's and 1's.

Comment: Thank you for help me answer my question but I have a error shows up >TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'float'

Comment: @Merlin sure: with integers n>1 you get n times the value. numpy behind fulfills python logic so you multiply n * 'column title'. That fits OP's matrix form though

Comment: @Merlin added a line to explain how to turn a float matrix quickly into a boolean one.